# JSF Navigation with Different CSS Class for Current/Active Path

Tags: jsf

I'm trying to create a menu template in JSF where the link for the current directory has a different "current" or "active" class. The code currently looks like:

```
<ul>
    <li><h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/a/">A</h:outputLink></li>
    <li><h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/b/">B</h:outputLink></li>
    <li><h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/c/">C</h:outputLink></li>
</ul>
```

I'm thinking of using something like `styleClass="#{(thisDir == currentDir) ? currentLinkClass : normalLinkClass}"`. But how do I get the current path? Is this even correct, or is there a better way to do this?

Also, I want the links to base on the current path, not just the page. For example, `myapp/a/1.jsf` and `myapp/a/2.jsf` (that is, `myapp/a/*.jsf`) should trigger the active class for the `A` link. (I hope my explanation is clear.) Is this possible? How should this be done?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`#{request.requestURI}`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29) to get the current request URI. You can if necessary use several EL functions from [JSTL `fn` taglib](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/fn/tld-summary.html) to do some string comparisons/manipulations in EL.

Your proposed EL `styleClass` suggestion is perfectly fine. There is no other easy way anyway. Best optimization which you could do so far is to render those links in a loop by an [`<ui:repeat>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/ui/repeat.html) so that code duplication is at least eliminated.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this approach which uses `#{view.viewId}`:

```
<h:outputLink 
  styleClass="#{(view.viewId.equals('/admin/authors.xhtml')) ? 'active' : 'inactive'}"
  value="authors.xhtml">Text</h:outputLink>
```